# R save list in disk

Tags: r, list, save

I have a list var1:

```
var1 <- list(c("parts of a day", "time in astronomy", "star"),  c("tree tall", "pine tree"), c("environmental condition", "climate"))
```

I want to save it in disk. For example, the saved file in disk must have the following in each row of the csv file:

```
"parts of a day" 
"time in astronomy" 
"star"
"Tree tall"
"pine tree"
"environmental condition" 
"climate"
```

I tried

```
capture.output(unlist(var1), file="a1.csv", append=FALSE)
```

but this is creating the following format:

```
[1] "parts of a day"          "time in astronomy"       "star"                    "tree tall"
```

[5] "pine tree"               "environmental condition" "climate"

How can this be solved? A code snippet would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `lapply(var1, function(x) cat(paste(x, collapse=", "), sep="\n", file='yourfile.txt', append=TRUE))`

Comment: I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: You said earlier that it should be in 3 rows

Comment: I get the expected output by `cat(unlist(var1), sep="\n", file='yourfile.txt')`

Comment: i want each term inside " " to be in each row of the csv file, but all are showing in a single row now.

Comment: I got it in 7 rows with `sep="\n"`

Comment: With this, I get it with the quotes and in 7 rows, I don't know what is the trouble in your side  ie. `cat(paste0("'", unlist(var1), "'"), file='john.txt', sep="\n")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
cat(paste0("'", unlist(var1), "'"), file='yourfile.txt', sep="\n")
```

Or instead of using `paste` we can make use of `shQuote`

```
cat(shQuote(unlist(var1)), file='john.txt', sep="\n")
```